# Dishwasher confusion

Tags: circuit-breaker, dishwasher

I’m trying to track a fault in my wiring to the dishwasher. Ive seen evidence of a critter chewing on a coating but nothing touching anything bare to ground out. The breaker trips instantly after I try to turn it on so I know something is not right, I’m just looking for a good starting point for the troubleshooting

Comment: I would disconnect the dish washer to verify the critter has not damaged the wiring in the walls if it doesn’t trip then start looking for arc marks in the dishwasher, if it trips with the dishwasher disconnected the critter has damaged the wiring before the dishwasher.

Comment: When the breaker trips, is it an overcurrent trip, or is a AFCI or GFCI trip?

Comment: I’m not sure about the AFCI or GFCI. The dishwasher is hardwired in and on it’s own breaker so disconnecting the wiring and checking the breaker itself should be fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the motor. With the power off, disconnect or unplug the leads to the motor. Then turn on the power and see if the breaker trips. If it doesn't, then the motor is the problem, check the winding for continuity. If is does trip, keep working back toward the main connection till you find the fault.